# Drupal 7 Gmap View No Markers Visible

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7, view, google-maps-markers

I have installed all modules needed.
If I set the view as table, I can see the 'location' fields (longitude,latitude, ...) but when I use Gmap as format I only see an empty Google map on de view-page.

I made a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of view settings]

What went wrong??

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear cache
2. Try to use Latitude/Longitude fields as data source instead of Location.module